# How use special characters in URL(Webview)?

Tags: android, url, android-webview, rfc

I am currently working on a project that  uses the following convention to authenticate users  through a webview:
https://username:password@domain.com

The problem arises when users have password with special characters. I have search around trying to find out  a possible solution.

I have tried using handler.proceed when I received an authentication request but have not been able to  have any success with that method.

The web view loadURL method only takes a string, is this string automatically URL encoded?

I current use  String.format(https://%s:%s@domain.com , username , password) to format the String

My question is it possible to use  the current convention with special characters in the password.

This seems to only be an issue on devices running any OS less than 4.4

Edits: for clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The web view loadURL method only takes a string, is this string automatically URL encoded?

No. This would lead to undesired results. Take your own url for example:

> https://username:password@domain.com

If that would be url-encoded before loading, it would turn into something like:

```
https%3A%2F%2Fusername%3Apassword%40domain.com
```

Clearly, that wouldn't make much sense.

> I current use `String.format(https://%s:%s@domain.com)` to format the String. (...) is it possible to use the current convention with special characters in the password.

Sure, just make sure you url-encoded the actual username and password. For example, let's say the username is an email address: `someone@somewhere.com`, and the password is something that contains some 'special' characters: `@bc:d`. Your current string formatter would turn your url into:

```
https://someone@somewhere.com:@bc:d@domain.com
```

Now, it should be obvious that that doesn't look right. Instead, url-encoding the username and password turns this into

```
https://someone%40somewhere.com:%40bc%3Ad@domain.com
```

Which is a perfectly legal url. The encoded username and password can/will then be decoded again on the receiving end.

To perform the url-encoding on Android, have a look at [`URLEncoded`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLEncoder.html) and [`Uri.encode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode(java.lang.String)).